# How to neatly place a picture to the left of a box in CSS

Tags: html, css, frontend

[image: Picture of the CSS]

I want to place the picture neatly in the middle and to the left of the of the box and the font in the middle of it. However, when I mess around with the margins and padding, it doesn't work out the way I want it to.

Here is my CSS and HTML for it.

CSS

```
 .wrap {
    width: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
  }

  .make-center {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .media-content {
    font-size: 100px;
  }

  .card {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin: 150px auto auto auto;
    width: 2000px;
    border-color: #1abc9c;
  }

  .card-content {
    width: 3000px;
    height: 200px;
  }

  .wrapper {
    /* border-bottom: 10px solid #1abc9c; */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px -6px #1abc9c;
    border-radius: 100px;
    margin: 200px auto;
    background: white;
    width: 50%;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 40px 20px;
  }

  .celeb-name {
    padding: 5px 10px 10px 5px;
  }
```

The .celeb-name does not place the celebrity's name in the middle when I include the picture and the picture becomes deformed when I use the 'padding' feature in CSS.

HTML

```
 <div class="star-list" id="star-box">
  <div class="star-list" id="star-box">
    <div class="card" data-name="${name}\">
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="media">
          <div class="media-left">
            <figure class="image is-48x48">
              <img
                src="https://api.buzzanglemusic.com/images/artists/1374"
                alt="Placeholder image"
              />
            </figure>
          </div>
          <div class="media-content">
            <p>1. DRAKE</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is utilizing Bootstrap a valid option for you?

Comment: Using CSS flexbox would do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 25%;
  box-size: border-box;
}

.star-list {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px -6px #1abc9c;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  height: 40px;
}

.star-list > img {
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.star-list > .media-content {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="star-list" id="star-box">
  <img src="https://api.buzzanglemusic.com/images/artists/1374" alt="Placeholder image" />
  <span class="media-content">
    1. DRAKE
  </span>
</div>
```

use `flex-box` to align the items center

code :

```
display : flex;
align-items : center;
```

And you don't have to use that much of divs, try to make it cleaner

Above is the improved code, if you want

Comment: to use flex-box, first, you have to make the element to flex i.e. `display: flex` and then apply whatever `flex` properties you want in your element.                                     
You can learn `flex-box`  from https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Answer (score 1):

I would utilize [CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox).

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 500px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 1px rgba(109, 103, 104, 0.88);
  
}

.celeb-img {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 5px;
 }
 
 .celeb-name {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <img class="celeb-img" src="https://api.buzzanglemusic.com/images/artists/1374" alt="Placeholder image" />
   <p class="celeb-name">1. Drake</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @joseezy Feel free to mess around with different `justify-content` CSS properties in order to achieve what you would like in terms of centering.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using CSS flexbox, try making div `media` as flexbox and then aligning its inner content as you want like,

```
.media{
    display:flex;
    align-items:center; /* will make the inner divs align vertically centered */
}
.media-left{
    width:40%; /* or as required */
}
.media-content{
    width:60%; /* or as required */
    font-size: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired output by using CSS Flexbox.
In your case, add flex to the container(media) which is wrapping both image and name.

```
.media{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
    align-items:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use Bootstrap, then you could utilize some of the many powerful classes within the framework.

For instance, you could make use of the flexbox classes and the grid system, as well as the responsive image classes.

**HTML:**

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrap-rounded d-flex">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row align-self-center justify-content-start">
        <div class="col-6 d-flex align-self-center">
            <img src="https://api.buzzanglemusic.com/images/artists/1374" class="img-responsive rounded-circle col-7 col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-12" alt="placeholder image" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12 d-flex justify-content-end align-self-center text-right card-text">
            1. Drake
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrap-rounded {
    width: 100%;
    height: 115px;
    border: 2px solid #7FFFD4;
    border-radius: 40px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 12px 10px 10px 0px rgba(127, 255, 212, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 12px 20px 01px 0px rgba(127, 255, 212, 1);
    box-shadow: 12px 10px 20px 0px rgba(127, 255, 212, 1);
}

.card-text {
    padding-right: 10%;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Codepen Example [here](https://codepen.io/mbacode/pen/jOWmMBm).

**Snippet:**

```css
.wrap-rounded {
    width: 100%;
    height: 115px;
    border: 2px solid #7FFFD4;
    border-radius: 40px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 12px 10px 10px 0px rgba(127, 255, 212, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 12px 20px 01px 0px rgba(127, 255, 212, 1);
    box-shadow: 12px 10px 20px 0px rgba(127, 255, 212, 1);
}

.card-text {
    padding-right: 10%;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrap-rounded d-flex">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row align-self-center justify-content-start">
        <div class="col-6 d-flex align-self-center">
            <img src="https://api.buzzanglemusic.com/images/artists/1374" class="img-responsive rounded-circle col-7 col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-12" alt="placeholder image" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12 d-flex justify-content-end align-self-center text-right card-text">
            1. Drake
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```